# Boot error while accessing bootable usb drive

Tags: boot, system-installation, usb, 17.10

So I downloaded ubuntu 17.10 since my computer needed a new OS. I created a bootable usb drive with Rufus and all seems well. However when I load the usb on my computer it gives the error
**Boot Error** 
And nothing happens. I have tried to format the drive and try again with 16.04 version and same result.

Comment: Some USB sticks do not work well as boot devices, but before you rush out to buy another, please check your BIOS to make sure that "secure boot" is turned off.

Comment: Can you try the drive on another computer, maybe a friends?